# 100% RAM usage in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am currently using google colab for one of my Deep learning projects of sign language recognition model, where I am loading my custom dataset which I created from Google Drive. My dataset contains different folder of alphabets which contains sign of respective alphabets.

This is just a part of code which i m using to create my training data

```
training_data = []
def create_training_data():
  for category in CATEGORIES:  
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to image of respective alphabet
    class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification  for each alphabet A : 0, C : 1, D : 2,...

    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  # iterate over each image
      img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
      training_data.append([img_array, class_num])  # add this to our training_data

create_training_data()

X = []
y = []

for features,label in training_data:
  X.append(np.array(features))
  y.append(label)
```

But just this process takes up all the available RAM, So is there any way I can do in order to minimize the RAM usage ??

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your training data set, so take this with a grain of salt.  If you use a generator for the training data instead of a building it up as a list then you should eliminate half of your memory usage.  You still pay the memory cost of X and Y, so this technique may not be sufficient to solve your problem.

```
def iter_training_data():
  for category in CATEGORIES:  
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to image of respective alphabet
    class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification  for each alphabet A : 0, C : 1, D : 2,...

    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  # iterate over each image
      img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
      yield [img_array, class_num]

X = []
y = []

for features,label in iter_training_data():
  X.append(np.array(features))
  y.append(label)
```

Comment: Consequently the same should apply to the features and labels.

Answer (score 0):

It takes up all the available RAM as you simply copy all of your data to it.

It might be easier to use `DataLoader` from PyTorch and define a size of the batch (for not using all the data at once).

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
    # transforms.Resize((256, 256)), # might also help in some way, if resize is allowed in your task
    transforms.ToTensor() ])

train_dir = '/path/to/train/data/'

train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, train_transforms)

batch_size = 32
train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size )
```

Then, on train phase you can do something like:

```
# ...
for inputs, labels in tqdm(train_dataloader):
    inputs = inputs.to(device)
    labels = labels.to(device)
    # ...
```